# Why isn't the alerts showing up?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trynna make a simple validation in JS by checking if the name entered has at least 5 characters and the age is over 18. This is what I have so far:

```
<body>
        <form method="POST">
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="John"><br>
            <label for="age">Age: </label>
            <input type="number" name="age" id="age"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
        </form>
        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            var userName = document.getElementById('name');
            var userAge = document.getElementById('age');
        
            function validationCheck(){
                if (userName.length < 5){
                    alert("Enter a miniumum of 5 characters.");
                }
                else if (parseInt(userAge) < 18){
                    alert("Underaged bigot!");
                }
                else if (userName.length < 5 && parseInt(userAge) < 18){
                    alert("Enter a miniumum of 5 characters you underaged bigot!")
                }
            }

            document.addEventListener("onclick", validationCheck())
            // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userAge;
            
        </script>
</body>
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong and why is it not working.

Comment: Be careful using strong language as test messages, especially when it's targeted at kids lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various issues with your code

1. in `if (userName.length < 5)`
   the variable `userName` is holding a `HTMLElement`, which doesn't have a length.
2. Same for `else if (parseInt(userAge) < 18)`.
3. `document.addEventListener("onclick", validationCheck())` has 2 problems

   1. the event is named `click` not `onclick`
   2. if you pass a functionname as eventhandler you must not use `()` in the end
4. Your last `else if` can never be executed, because if either one of its conditions is true, one of the first two cases will be hit and the last `else if` won't be evaluated. You should put that case on the top.
5. Are you sure, want to attach your validationCheck on every click in the document? This will fire also if someone clicks on any empty place in the document or tries to focus an input with the mouse.
6. You should initialize the input for the age with a valid number, otherwise `parseInt(userAge.value)` will return `NaN` and the age check will fail.

```html
<body>
        <form method="POST">
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="John"><br>
            <label for="age">Age: </label>
            <input type="number" name="age" id="age" value="0"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
        </form>
        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            var userName = document.getElementById('name');
            var userAge = document.getElementById('age');
        
            function validationCheck(){
                if (userName.value.length < 5 && parseInt(userAge.value) < 18){
                    alert("Enter a miniumum of 5 characters you underaged bigot!")
                } else if (userName.value.length < 5){
                    alert("Enter a miniumum of 5 characters.");
                }
                else if (parseInt(userAge.value) < 18){
                    alert("Underaged bigot!");
                }
            }

            document.addEventListener("click", validationCheck)
            // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userAge;
            
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: So if I want to make sure that both my variables can have a length then I should initialize them first?

5. Yeah I have an issue with trying to only show the alert pop ups when only someone doesn't fulfil the conditions. But I have no idea how to do that :/

Answer (score 0):

You're using `.length` on the wrong object. Your `userName` is the `<input id="name" ...>` object, not the actual value. To get the value, read `.value`:

```js
var userName = document.getElementById('name').value;
var userAge = document.getElementById('age').value;
```

Next time you have an issue like this, add some `console.log` statements or breakpoints. You would've noticed that your `userName` are DOM elements instead of strings.

Comment: You are aware, that when you put that code on the same position as it currently is, it will only be evaluted a single time when the document is loaded and the variables won't be updated with the values from the inputs later on ...

Comment: I am aware, but totally missed that `validationCheck()` could (if it was used right) be called multiple times. Seems like his event listener is also wrongly set up.